# What is the MakerNote Apple 0x0002 field in iPhone/iPad images? Is it a unique identifier for photos?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, camera, exif

What is the MakerNote Apple 0x0002 field in iPhone/iPad images? Is it a unique identifier for photos?

Example:

> [MakerNotes]    Apple 0x0002                    :
>   bplist00O..?~yvronlkigc]F".???{ws[...]

Answer (score 2):

`bplist` would suggest it's a binary property list.

If you can pull out the raw binary, you can decode it. There are some command line tools available. Search for `bplist` online.

If that fails, a discussion of the format is available here:

https://synalysis.com/how-to-decode-apple-binary-property-list-files/

My guess would be that the excellent Exiftool will decode this field for you.

I maintain an image metadata software library (for Java and .NET) and would be interested in a sample image with this field. Perhaps I can add support in my software. If you have time, please [open an issue](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/new) and attach a sample image.

Comment: Hi Drew! Could you add the most important points from your link to your post? It improves readability and insures against the website changing/being taken down.

Comment: @JMY1000 I did not feel that a discussion of the binary format of bplist was asked for, and included it only in case the OP was technically inclined to dig into the details. The real value in my answer was the identification that it's encoded data, and the format is `bplist`. That directly addresses the OP's question.

Comment: Fair enough. Carry on!